# NSInvalidArgumentException: +[NSBundle fyb_appTransportSecuritySettings]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3bd0c3c0

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to add Heyzap to monetize my project. I'm using unity and I'm trying to integrate the sdk of Heyzap (with AdColony, UnityAds, Chartboost and AdMob). But I'm getting this error when I try to initialize the plugin:

```
2016-09-20 17:58:42.429 trending[499:60b] +[NSBundle fyb_appTransportSecuritySettings]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3bd0c3c0
2016-09-20 17:58:43.071 trending[499:60b] Uncaught exception: NSInvalidArgumentException: +[NSBundle fyb_appTransportSecuritySettings]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3bd0c3c0
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x30dcdf6b <redacted> + 154
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3b4386af objc_exception_throw + 38
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x30dd17f3 <redacted> + 202
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x30dd01d3 <redacted> + 706
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x30d1f598 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
    5   trending                            0x00d8ab57 -[FyberSDK init] + 74
    6   trending                            0x00d8aa9b +[FyberSDK instance] + 138
    7   trending                            0x00d8acc3 +[FyberSDK interstitialController] + 20
    8   trending                            0x00d7ef0b -[HZFYBInterstitialManager init] + 72
    9   trending                            0x00d7d2d5 -[HZWrapperManager init] + 152
    10  trending                            0x00d7d225 __33+[HZWrapperManager sharedManager]_block_invoke + 48
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x3b91bd67 <redacted> + 22
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x3b9237ff <redacted> + 42
    13  trending                            0x00d7d1ef +[HZWrapperManager sharedManager] + 62
    14  trending                            0x00d7de97 +[HZIncentivizedAd setDelegate:] + 50
    15  trending                            0x004e8969 __hz_ads_start_app_block_invoke + 300
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x3b91bd67 <redacted> + 22
    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x3b9237ff <redacted> + 42
    18  trending                            0x004e883b hz_ads_start_app + 100
    19  trending                            0x000b474f HeyzapAds_Start_m2477159166 + 58
    20  trending                            0x000b84b7 AdManager_Start_m2207418645 + 102
    21  trending                            0x004c2021 _Z31RuntimeInvoker_Void_t1841601450PK10MethodInfoPvPS2_ + 14
    22  trending                            0x00d1cfad _ZN6il2cpp2vm7Runtime6InvokeEPK10MethodInfoPvPS5_PP15Il2CppException + 116
    23  trending                            0x006637b7 _ZN19ScriptingInvocation6InvokeEPP18ScriptingExceptionb + 38
    24  trending                            0x0065912b _ZN13MonoBehaviour30InvokeMethodOrCoroutineCheckedE21ScriptingMethodIl2CppP15ScriptingObjectPP18ScriptingException + 1142
    25  trending                            0x006592c7 _ZN13MonoBehaviour30InvokeMethodOrCoroutineCheckedE21ScriptingMethodIl2CppP15ScriptingObject + 26
    26  trending                            0x00658467 _ZN13MonoBehaviour16DelayedStartCallEP6ObjectPv + 54
    27  trending                            0x0055c329 _ZN18DelayedCallManager6UpdateEi + 476
    28  trending                            0x0061bbc3 _Z10PlayerLoopbbP10IHookEvent + 810
    29  trending                            0x0082dd07 _ZL19UnityPlayerLoopImplb + 14
    30  trending                            0x00098df3 UnityRepaint + 218
    31  trending                            0x00098cbd -[UnityAppController(Rendering) repaintDisplayLink] + 76
    32  libglInterpose.dylib                0x0283fa67 -[DYDisplayLinkInterposer forwardDisplayLinkCallback:] + 270
    33  QuartzCore                          0x33217f2f <redacted> + 98
    34  QuartzCore                          0x33217cd9 <redacted> + 344
    35  IOMobileFramebuffer                 0x35de976d <redacted> + 104
    36  IOKit                               0x31aaed05 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 248
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x30d8de29 <redacted> + 136
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x30d989e7 <redacted> + 34
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x30d98983 <redacted> + 346
    40  CoreFoundation                      0x30d97157 <redacted> + 1398
    41  CoreFoundation                      0x30d01ce7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
    42  CoreFoundation                      0x30d01acb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
    43  GraphicsServices                    0x359cf283 GSEventRunModal + 138
    44  UIKit                               0x335a3a41 UIApplicationMain + 1136
    45  trending                            0x0009137b main + 202
    46  libdyld.dylib                       0x3b940ab7 <redacted> + 2
)
2016-09-20 17:58:43.078 trending[499:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSBundle fyb_appTransportSecuritySettings]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3bd0c3c0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x30dcdf53 0x3b4386af 0x30dd17f3 0x30dd01d3 0x30d1f598 0xd8ab57 0xd8aa9b 0xd8acc3 0xd7ef0b 0xd7d2d5 0xd7d225 0x3b91bd67 0x3b9237ff 0xd7d1ef 0xd7de97 0x4e8969 0x3b91bd67 0x3b9237ff 0x4e883b 0xb474f 0xb84b7 0x4c2021 0xd1cfad 0x6637b7 0x65912b 0x6592c7 0x658467 0x55c329 0x61bbc3 0x82dd07 0x98df3 0x98cbd 0x283fa67 0x33217f2f 0x33217cd9 0x35de976d 0x31aaed05 0x30d8de29 0x30d989e7 0x30d98983 0x30d97157 0x30d01ce7 0x30d01acb 0x359cf283 0x335a3a41 0x9137b 0x3b940ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Any help will be welcome. Thank you

Comment: What plugin version? What Unity version? What iOS version? These you should also post why getting exceptions like these. Also, does this only happen on iOS? Does it work on Android?

Comment: @Programmer Unity 5.4, lastest plugun version (i've downloaded today) and it works fine in Android.

Answer (score 2):

Can you check to see if the `-ObjC` flag is in your "Other Linker Flags" in the Xcode project? See here on how to check: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYanp.jpg

source: I'm an iOS engineer at Heyzap.

(note: this should be automatically done for you - have a look at the Unity Editor log and the console log to see if anything weird stands out, and feel free to reply or contact support@heyzap.com if you see something)